# Restore Alt-Tab behavior so that minimizing an app once again moves it to the end?

Tags: windows-xp, alt-tab

Having used Windows for 20+ years, I'm totally used to minimizing an app to effectively remove it from alt-tab order - that is, I "put it away" temporarily by moving it to the end of the list.  This has stopped working in XP.  Is there a way to restore it rather than switching to some over-the-top powertoy?

Comment: My question exactly. When did this stop working in XP, and why?

Comment: Seems to still work for me (and I'm up to date with patches). Does it work for a simple app like Notepad?

Comment: No. I've noticed that minimised Firefox goes to the end of the list, but not any other programs (including Notepad).

Comment: I can’t figure out what you mean. How exactly is it “removed”? What happens now that you consider to be wrong? And what exactly do you mean by “end of the list”?

Answer (score 1):

Try Alt+Esc as a replacement, it have the same effect - to put the current item to the back of the Alt-Tab list.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't really answer my question, but I didn't know that before and it's good to know.

Comment: Alt-Esc wow that was manic.  i'm surprised I survived that and found this page again!